# Is there any difference in the output of nvvp (visual) and nvprof (command line)?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvvp, nvprof

To measure metrics/events for CUDA programs, I have tried using the command line like:

```
nvprof --metrics <<metric_name>>
```

I also measured the same metrics on the Visual profiler `nvvp`. I noticed no difference in the values I get.

I noticed a difference in output when I choose a metric like `achieved_occupancy`. But this varies with every execution and that's probably why I get different results each time I run it, irrespective of whether I am using `nvvp` or `nvprof`.

**The question:**

I was under the impression that `nvvp` and `nvprof` are exactly the same, and that `nvvp` is simply a GUI built on top of `nvprof` for ease of use. However I have been given this advice:

> Always use the visual profiler. Never use the command line.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699141/cuda-visual-profiler-over-a-remote-x-session) says:

> I do not want to use the command line profiler as I need the global load/store efficiency, replay and DRAM utilization, which are much more visible in the visual profiler.

Apart from 'dynamic' metrics like `achieved_occupancy`, I never noticed any differences in results. So, is this advice valid? Is there some sort of deficiency in the way `nvprof` works? I would like to know the advantages of using the visual profiler over the command line form, if there are any.

More specifically, are there metrics for which `nvprof` gives wrong results?

**Note:**

My question is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254512/nvvp-and-nsights-profiler-give-a-different-result?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402775/nvidia-parallel-nsight-vs-visual-profiler?rq=1) because these are asking about the difference between `nvvp` and Nsight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why someone would give you the advice:

> Never use the command line.

assuming by "command line" you do in fact mean `nvprof`.  **That's not sensible.**  There are situations where it makes sense to use `nvprof`.  (Note that if you actually meant the *command line profiler*, then that advice might be somewhat sensible, although still a matter of preference.  It is separate from `nvprof` so has a separate learning curve.  I personally would use `nvprof` instead of [the command line profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#compute-command-line-profiler-overview).)

`nvvp` uses `nvprof` under the hood, in order to do **all** of its measurement work.  However `nvvp` may combined measured metrics in various interesting ways, e.g. to facilitate guided analysis.

`nvprof` should not give you "wrong results", and if it did for some reason, then `nvvp` should be equally susceptible to such errors.

Use of `nvvp` vs. `nvprof` may be simply a matter of taste or preference.

Many folks will like the convenenience of the GUI.  And the `nvvp` GUI offers a "Guided Analysis" mode which `nvprof` does not.  I'm sure there could be created an exhaustive list of other differences if you go through the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#abstract).  But whatever `nvvp` does, it does it using `nvprof`.  It doesn't have an alternate method to query the device for profiler data -- it uses `nvprof`.

I would use `nvprof` when it's inconvenient to use `nvvp`, perhaps when I am running on a compute cluster node where it's difficult or impossible to launch `nvvp`.  You might also use it if you are doing targetted profiling (measuring a single metric, e.g. `shared_replay_overhead` - `nvprof`is certainly quicker than firing up the GUI and running a session), or if you are collecting metrics for tabular generation over a large series of runs.

In most other cases, I personally would use `nvvp`.  The timeline feature itself is hugely more convenient than trying to assemble a sequence in your head from the output of `nvprof --print-gpu-trace ...` which is essentially the same info as the timeline.

Comment: Yes, by command line I did mean `nvprof`. I was using `nvprof` to measure a single metric but I was told not to, hence I was wondering if `nvvp` and `nvprof` worked differently, so thanks for mentioning that "whatever `nvvp` does, it does it using `nvprof`".

Comment: Actually `nvprof` only was [added](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-nvprof-your-handy-universal-gpu-profiler/) in [CUDA 5](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_0/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_And_Errata.txt) while the visual profiler already existed in CUDA 2.1. But I think both use [CUPTI](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/) under the hood. And with `nvprof -o out.sqlite3` you can create the timeline and with `nvprof --analysis-metrics -o out-profile.sqlite3` you can create all other data needed for `nvvp`. You can then import both files in `nvvp`.